# Как показать картинки если сделал маршрутизацию через .htaccess

Tags: php, маршрутизация

В.htaccess написано:

`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule (.*) /index.php?$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>`

В index.php я получаю `explode("/", key($_GET));` и выбираю какой файл php загружать, но из-за этого непонятно как выводить картинки из папок, так как все запросы идут на index.php.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

В таком случае Вы сможете обращаться к файлам, которые лежат относительно дерриктории в которой лежит index.php.

Comment: Да, я смогу обращаться к файлами, но тогда я не получу `explode("/", key($_GET));`.